# CSS3 Wrapper Fading In/Out outside the box

Tags: css, wrapper, fade

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru54p/

CCS3:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 660px;
    max-width: 70%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fade { 
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="fade">
    <div id="wrapper">
            BLAH<BR>
            BLAH<BR>
            BLAH<BR>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the jsfiddle, for some reason it's fading when you hover the cursor outside out of the box... I think it has something to do with the width, any ideas?

Comment: i don´t know what you want, but thats exactly what you told css that should do, the .fade div on hover turns opacity to 0.5 what did you really want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because your inner div i.e. the div with class wrapper has width only 70% of the parent div i.e. div with class fade.

and you have applied opacity css i.e. .fade to the parent

so either increase the width of the inner div to 100% i.e.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 660px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

or apply the hover property on wrapper i.e apply the .fade class on wrapper

```
<div >
     <div id="wrapper" class="fade">
         BLAH<BR>BLAH<BR>BLAH<BR>
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/mqRfW/)

Comment: `<div id="wrapper" class="fade">`

that did the job, ty.

Comment: yup lol thank you, im still learning all the different ways to group and stack classes/id's

Answer (score 0):

A `div` is block-level by default, so it will take up all the available width. You are applying your transition to the `.fade` class, but it appears you want only the `#wrapper` itself to fade.

Try applying a background-color to the `.fade` block to illustrate what's going on. The fix is to either add your opacity etc. to your `#wrapper`, or to set another property on your `fade` class to limit the width (e.g. set it to `display: inline-block;`).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated code,

you were having wrong sequence of div,

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ru54p/3/

I hope this will do :)

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 660px;
    max-width: 70%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fade {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    padding:10px 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="background:#222">
    <br /><div id="wrapper">
    <div class="fade">
    BLAH<BR />BLAH<BR />BLAH<BR />
    </div></div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: MarmiK, welcome to StackOverflow - it is good to see you are an active contributer. As a general rule, please include all relevant code in your answers and provide links only as a reference - you're answer should still make sense without having to leave the SO site.